# How does the bitcoin client determine the first IP address to connect?

Tags: p2p, bitcoin

In my knowledge, bitcoin is a p2p protocol and [a p2p protocol must have a dedicated central server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310607/peer-to-peer-methods-of-finding-peers). But it is said that bitcoin is **decentralized**.

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/how-do-bitcoin-clients-find-each-other

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Back in 2009 we relied on IRC to bootstrap the network, so every node would connect to Freenode (later LFnet) and would join a channel. Their nicknames were their encoded public IP address.

Nowadays the Bitcoin Core client, and many other implementations, rely on DNS seeds. DNS seeds are special DNS servers that are configured to return a number of randomly selected nodes from the network. The operators of the DNS seeds also run crawlers to enumerate the publicly reachable nodes that are to be returned by the seeds.

The seeds that are currently included in the Bitcoin Core client are:

- bitcoin.sipa.be
- dnsseed.bluematt.me
- dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org
- seed.bitcoinstats.com
- bitseed.xf2.org
- bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch

If you send a request to any of these servers they will return a number of random IPs that are known to run Bitcoin on port 8333:

```
dig seed.bitcoinstats.com +short
71.19.155.244
173.254.232.51
45.79.97.30
198.252.112.64
35.128.8.141
108.17.18.165
98.208.76.134
8.29.28.12
52.62.2.124
96.234.214.85
47.89.24.56
212.164.215.159
52.62.42.229
68.52.96.191
115.66.205.171
24.250.16.39
201.43.160.155
5.3.253.18
100.40.179.172
50.135.169.181
186.149.249.18
101.201.44.207
96.35.97.46
124.188.118.196
82.8.4.79
```

Besides the DNS seeds, the Core client also has a [static list of IPs](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparamsseeds.h) to try first and it will cache any previously contacted peers in a local database in order to reconnect without having to query the DNS seeds.

(Disclaimer: I am the operator of one of the DNS seeds)

Comment: What I concerned is: is there a risk that the DNS server is shutdown or blocked by outer forces that lead to the death of bitcoin?

Comment: The DNS seeds are but one of several mechanisms to perform the bootstrap. In case of a total block you might not even notice anything if you were connected before, because your node will simply try to reconnect to some previously known peers or the static list. Even if you are bootstrapping you could simply ask someone for their IP and use the `-addnode` command line flag to connect to it.

Comment: How exactly does one send a request to these?

Comment: The request is done via the standard DNS protocol. On the command line you can use the DNS 'dig' tool, as shown above:  `dig bitcoin.sipa.be A` for IPv4 addresses or   `dig dnsseed.bluematt.me AAAA` for IPv6 addresses, for example

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can do an NSLookup like this:

```
nslookup seed.bitcoinstats.com
Server:  Fios_Quantum_Gateway.e
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    seed.bitcoinstats.com
Addresses:  2600:1900:4000:4cc4:0:1::
          138.68.173.152
          142.93.200.9
          52.205.232.109
          52.30.154.84
          213.174.156.82
          34.241.94.237
          18.202.91.9
          51.79.82.75
          54.68.82.186
          69.4.94.226
          153.127.253.219
          69.55.55.188
          198.27.83.210
          116.203.99.217
          3.8.38.104
          51.195.28.51
          34.249.21.210
          46.137.123.109
          37.187.129.27
          13.112.109.34
          74.118.140.132
          64.227.26.97
          3.211.51.136
          3.81.243.143
          95.168.162.24
```

Those are the results at the time I write this, but they may change over time for each DNS seed.

Note that **you** don't actually need to do this; your Bitcoin Core node will do this automatically when it first starts up, and it will check several of the listed DNS seeds to get a starting list of nodes to connect to.

Once it connects to those nodes, it will ask each for a list of Bitcoin nodes *they* know about, and each will return up to a thousand more peer addresses.

Your node will very quickly amass of list of thousands of potential peer addresses to use when looking for peers.

Even if some third party tries to block *some* of the DNS seeds, they are unlikely to be able to block all of them, and a new Bitcoin Core node will keep trying until it connects to at least three, IIRC.

And, as CDecker notes above, even if they are all somehow inaccessible (via country-wide firewall, perhaps), asking for one valid IP address of another node from someone online can still get you started, and soon you've have thousands of address in your peers lists.