# Participation in a Kademlia network via DNS seeds

Tags: dns, p2p, dht, kademlia

If a node wants to participate in a Kademlia network, it will look-up a [bootstrap node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_node) as part of the bootstrapping process. In fact, this [Java implementation](https://github.com/JoshuaKissoon/Kademlia) seems to do the same.

In the Bitcoin protocol, too, a node will look up to know, who are the other peer nodes. And, the preferred mode seems to be DNS seeds. Quoting from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41708702/919480),

> Nowadays the Bitcoin Core client, and many other implementations, rely
>   on DNS seeds. DNS seeds are special DNS servers that are configured to
>   return a number of randomly selected nodes from the network. The
>   operators of the DNS seeds also run crawlers to enumerate the publicly
>   reachable nodes that are to be returned by the seeds.

Does such a look-up mechanism exist for Kademlia nodes?

Comment: Kademlia is an overlay network design and routing algorithm. It is something abstract. So are you asking how to design a specific feature as extension of such a network? Or on top of such a network? Or about a specific implementation? Or how the bootstrap works once you can contact the first node (this is covered in the paper)?

Comment: The Bitcoin Core client seems to rely on DNS seeds before it knows of the first node. My question is, can Kademlia rely on DNS seeds to look up the first node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, can Kademlia rely on DNS seeds to look up the first node?

Yes, that is one possibility. Ideally you will want to use DNS SRV records to allow non-standard ports, but A/AAAA records will do too if the seed nodes have known ports.