# Is it possible to establish a connection between 2 computers without they knowing the IP of the other computer beforehand? If so, how?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, decentralized-applications

I suppose this is a little bit of a decentralized computing question. If you want to write a software with no kind of authoritarian server that the clients already have some kind of address to, is it possible to make 2 clients/computers find eachother on the internet and have them send TCP or UDP packages between them?

If so, how? And how does softwares like Bitcoin solve this problem?

*If anyone were to provide any code examples, python or C++ would be my preferred languages*

Comment: Relevant info here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673073/how-does-the-bitcoin-client-determine-the-first-ip-address-to-connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It generally isn't possible. Decentralized systems solve the problem by finding each other's IP addresses from somewhere. Usually there's an authoritative server that the clients know the address of. Perhaps the only alternative is by by asking your friend and typing it into the software. Some viruses simply guessed random addresses, but that doesn't work all that well.

Most decentralized systems make it so each node shares the IP addresses it knows with the nodes it's connected to, so that IP addresses can spread throughout the network. If your system does this, then it's not really that bad to have a server which shares some "getting started" IP addresses, as the client can learn the rest of them from the network. The risk is that the server could go bad and put clients onto the wrong network not connected to the main network.

Answer (score -1):

To link up without prior knowledge of their IP addresses, Distributed Hash Tables (DHT) are a decentralized method for peer discovery that can enable clients to find and connect with one another.

Creating a fault-tolerant infrastructure, DHT is a decentralized system that enables nodes to store and fetch data in a distributed manner. Peer-to-peer networks often implement DHT which makes it scalable. Nodes within this network hold a small fraction of the hash table, utilizing it to map values to their relevant keys.

To connect to the system, a client will reach out to a bootstrap node, an established member within the network. By doing so, they will receive a rundown of nodes or linkages to others in the DHT network from the bootstrap. After the initial step, the client can then interact with these nodes and swap important data. A specific identifier or key is created, tied to either the individual or information they aim to distribute, and the client hashes this key to complete a DHT lookup.

sample code in python

```
import socket
import threading
import random

# DHT to store peer information
peer_dht = {}

# Function to handle incoming connections from other peers
def handle_connection(client_socket):
    while True:
        data = client_socket.recv(1024)  # Receive data from the peer
        if not data:
            break
        print(f"Received data: {data.decode()}")

    client_socket.close()

# Function to connect to a random peer in the DHT and send data
def connect_to_peer():
    if not peer_dht:
        print("No peers available.")
        return

    peer_ip, peer_port = random.choice(list(peer_dht.items()))

    peer_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        peer_socket.connect((peer_ip, peer_port))  # Connect to the peer
        while True:
            message = input("Enter a message to send: ")
            if message.lower() == "exit":
                break
            peer_socket.sendall(message.encode())  # Send data to the peer
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Connection refused.")
    finally:
        peer_socket.close()

# Main function to start the program
def main():
    # Get the local IP address
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

    # Start a listening socket to accept incoming connections
    listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    listen_socket.bind((local_ip, 8000))  # Use a specific port number
    listen_socket.listen(1)

    print(f"Listening for incoming connections on {local_ip}:8000")

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connected to peer at {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")

        # Add the peer to the DHT
        peer_dht[client_address[0]] = client_address[1]

        # Start a new thread to handle the connection
        threading.Thread(target=handle_connection, args=(client_socket,)).start()

    listen_socket.close()

# Entry point of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You need to already be connected to a P2P network before you can use a DHT.